# What causes excel to put quotes around text?

Tags: excel, quotes

I'm currently copying data (mainly text) from excel and pasting it into a CMS. Roughly 1 out of every 40-50 cells I copy will have quotes around the text. Is there a verified reason for this?

I'm currently under an NDA, so I'll change the words around, but not the punctuation 

 Examples: 

 Copied with quotes - "Blah color-coded blah blah #boopdifloop blah. bliff, too. Bliggityblaow #Hoopdederp. 

 " 

 Copied w/o qoutes - Shwiggityshwo frekin frakil one-of-a-kindness on your Goop #Likewhoa. Visit #Hoopdederp.

Comment: I assumed the same originally, but I haven't been able to correlate a specific punctuation mark to the issue. There are dots and commas rampantly used in the text I'm copying, but only some of the cells have this problem. Aren't text qualifiers used primarily when importing to excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured it out. It has to do with having an unused multi-line string after the text.